# Добавление данных в access ado.net

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, ado.net, ms-access

Сразу скажу я только учусь.

У меня есть поля в wpf и таблица access
при нажатии на кнопку добавить должно соответственно происходить добавление в бд.

Я сделал по аналогии с sqllocaldb но чет не работает

Подскажите пожалуйста чего не так. Код ниже

```
this.daAccess = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            this.dtAccess = new DataTable();
            var sql = @"INSERT INTO ORDERS (email,  product_number,  product_name) 
                             VALUES (@email,  @product_number,  @product_name); 
                 SET @id = @@IDENTITY;";

            daAccess.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql, accessConnection);

            daAccess.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", OleDbType.Integer, 4, "Id").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            daAccess.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@email", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "email");
            daAccess.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@product_number", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "product_number");
            daAccess.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@product_name", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "product_name");
            #endregion

            daAccess.Fill(dtAccess);
            gridViewAccess.DataContext = dtAccess.DefaultView;
```

Это что, что в кнопке

```
 DataRow r = dtAccess.NewRow();
            r["email"] = newEmailAccess.Text;
            r["product_number"] = newProductNumber.Text;
            r["product_name"] = newProductName.Text;
            dtAccess.Rows.Add(r);
            daAccess.Update(dtAccess);
```

При попытке добавить данные выходит вот такая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А при попытке изменить вот такая

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."
```

Comment: акцес не поддерживает мультистейтмент

Comment: @Konst не особо понимаю что это значит) типо надо через ExecuteNonQuery?

Comment: SET @id = @@IDENTITY; - это лишнее

Comment: соответственно и параметр @id не нужен

Comment: Либо хранимку используйте, как в [документации](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-identity-or-autonumber-values), либо получайте айдишник отдельным запросом: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47447217/5045688.

Comment: Ещё один вариант решения проблемы: использовать GUID, который генерируется на клиенте. Тогда не нужно получать его из БД.

Answer (score 0):

`SET @id = @@IDENTITY;` - это лишнее

соответственно и параметр `@id` не нужен